# Use Bootstrap by link or install in enviroment (pip install django-bootstrap3) in Django

Tags: python, css, django, bootstrapping

I'm newbie of Django. I just find out there is 2 ways of loading bootstrap in Django with:

```
1. <link rel="stylesheet" href="" crossorigin="anonymous">: For CDN or local file.

2. Installing in enviroment with (pip install django-bootstrap3): Loading by {% load bootstrap3 %}
```

Which way do you prefer in this case? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I am myself developing a full stack web app (with mobile app). And believe me the embedded link method is way better for your project Because :

1. Can anytime switch to latest version of bootstrap
2. Is portable (Don't need to configure/Install on different environments or servers.)
3. Faster than the other alternative.

Hope You got my point :)